# How can we change the quality of image/video which is streamed over web_video_server

Tags: ros, usb-cam-node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using the usb-cam node to get the video from my webcam and using web video server to stream it in my private network. But the average bandwidth  is about 20MBps . I do not have that much link speed. What should be done to reduce it
so that i can stream without any buffering.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213357/how-can-we-change-the-quality-of-image/video-which-is-streamed-over-web_video_server/) by [robobee](https://answers.ros.org/users/22791/robobee/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2015-07-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See the [web_video_server wiki page](http://wiki.ros.org/web_video_server).

There's the description of the different video encoding parameters.

You can set these parameters within the URL e.g.:
http://localhost:8888/stream?topic=depthcloud_encoded&bitrate=250000&type=vp8

uses the VP8 compression with a bitrate of 250k.

---

Originally posted by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) with karma: 2949 on 2015-07-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0